# Protractor wait for visibility of element

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm dying for a second day trying to make it works and seems like I'm missing something about promises or selectors...

```
browser.get(__url);
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.buttonText('Log in'))),20000);
element(by.buttonText('Log in')).click();
```

Even if button is on screen, it's never happens.

HTML is

```
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" ng-click="OnLogin()" ng-hide="authorized_user" data-upgraded=",MaterialButton,MaterialRipple">
    Log in
    <span class="mdl-button__ripple-container">
        <span class="mdl-ripple is-animating" style="width: 424.185px; height: 424.185px; transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translate(187px, 14px);"></span>
    </span>
</button>
```

My guess is button considered as display, even if I cannot see it, but I have no clue how to debug it, `console.log` will no do cause of async nature of tests

Comment: Try using `element(by.partialButtonText('Log in'))` locator.

Comment: Be aware that `EC.visibilityOf` doesn't really test the visibility from a user point of view. It simply checks that the element is displayed with a positive size while `click` is asserting that the element on top at the location is your element or an ancestor. So in your case either the element is hidden with an overlay or you've got a second button in the page with the same text.

Answer (score -1):

try `browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(loaded),waitTime);`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made